# Pass date value from one session to another session in the same workflow

Tags: informatica

I have two sessions i a workflow like below

workflow1->session1->session2

i have a join_date column in a table in Mapping1 , in session1

i want to pick this join_date value and pass to  mpping2/session2

If join date value changes in the table in session1 then the same value should pick and pass to session2

I will use this date value in a query in session2 .

Please tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Check the below link.
Similar issue has been answered.
https://community.informatica.com/thread/34581
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using mapping and workflow variables.

1. In mapping1 create a mapping variable say `var1` and set its value to join_date.
2. Create a workflow variable in the workflow, say `var_wkf`
3. In session1, in **Post-session on success variable assignment**, assign `var_wkf = var1`
4. In mapping2, create a mapping variable, say `var2`
5. In session2, in **Pre-session variable assignment**, assign `var2=var_wkf`
6. You can use the var2 variable in mapping2, it should have the value set in mapping1