# Mapping variable is not set in Mapping

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to realize some mappings as supposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894211/set-mapping-variable-in-expression-and-use-it-in-source-filter). I created a mapping, which reads from a table in which a date for incremental load is stored. After that I set a mapping variable to pass this date value to the next mapping. In the *Post-session on success variable assignment* the mapping variable is stored in a workflow variable and passed to the next mapping.

Here is the mapping to read the date value and store it in the mapping variable. The value is stored in the variable in the expression, the port is an output, which is linked to a dummy target. This target simply writes it in a flat file.

The port expression is `SETVARIABLE($$LOAD_FROM_DATE,LOAD_DATE)`.

[image: Mapping]

My problem is that the value is read correctly, but it is not persisted in the mapping variable. It is always falling back on the date default value. Where is my mistake?

Comment: How did you define the mapping variable? Which data type? As Min or Max variable?

Comment: The type is date/time and the Aggregation is Max. IsExpressionVar is set to false.

Comment: Ok, so it's a Max aggregation. Can you also tell us the values you're evaluating? What's the default, what's the LOAD_DATE? And how many rows are read from source?

Answer (score 0):

So you basically need to calculate a value from one mapping and use it in the second? If so, I have implemented something similar and it works fine for me. I have the port where I set variable (RESULT_LOAD in your case) value marked as a variable port. In the workflow you will be defining a variable to capture the variable value from mapping, mark it as persistent so that the value is stored in the repository after each run.